# System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find method: Process

Tags: sxa, publishing

I am getting an issues while publishing in the `content editor`.

Here is the full error if it will help

```
Job started: Publish to 'web'|Items created: 0|Items deleted: 0|Items updated: 0|Items skipped: 2|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find method: Process. Pipeline: /sitecore[database="SqlServer" sxaxm:require="sxaxconnect" patch:source="Test.Feature.AzureB2C.Serialization.config" unicorn:require="On" sxa:require="On" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"]/pipelines[require="sxaxconnect" patch:source="Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics.config"]/publish[help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishProcessor"]/processor[type="Test.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Overrides.CacheClearer, Test.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" patch:source="Test.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.CacheClear.config"]
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethodInfo(ProcessorObject obj, Object[] parameters)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

Comment: could you please mentioned which Sitecore version you are using?

Comment: also, have you done any customisation in the index configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a closer look at the first line of your exception, you will see the answer:

> `Job started: Publish to 'web'|Items created: 0|Items deleted: 0|Items updated: 0|Items skipped: 2|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find method: Process. Pipeline: /sitecore[database="SqlServer" sxaxm:require="sxaxconnect" patch:source="Test.Feature.AzureB2C.Serialization.config" unicorn:require="On" sxa:require="On" xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/"]/pipelines[require="sxaxconnect" patch:source="Sitecore.LayoutService.Analytics.config"]/publish[help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishProcessor"]/processor[type="Test.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Overrides.CacheClearer, Test.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" patch:source="Test.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.CacheClear.config"]`

See the sentence: *publish Processors should derive from Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishProcessor*

Apparently your `Test.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Overrides.CacheClearer` does not inherit from the processor mentioned above. Make sure that it does inherit and your issue will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my initial analysis, it appears that the issue may be related to improper index configuration. If you have performed any index customization, please review the *`solrConfig.xml`* file and ensure that the start and end tags of all nodes are correct. If no customization has been done, open the *`showconfig.aspx`* of your instance and examine all *`AddCrawler`* entries under the location node. Verify that each node has the appropriate root node.